# Rails help model design problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having that problem when I update my konkurrencer the do_foobar is called. The problem is that the konkurrancer have no ratings. And I get a off course a ZeroDivisionerror.

What is the best solution to solve this kind of problem?

My model:

```
before_update :do_foobar
def do_foobar
  self.rating = (rating_score/ratings)
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
self.rating = (ratings == 0) ? nil : rating_score/ratings
```

or

```
self.rating = rating_score/ratings rescue nil
```

Answer (score 1):

if you always do

`self.rating = 0 if ratings == 0 else (rating_score/ratings)`

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way would be to catch the error on the spot.

```
rating = rating_score - ratings rescue 0
```

This will instantly catch the `ZeroDivisionError` and pass the `0` through. (Be careful though. It will also catch and rescue any other error happening inside your `rating_score` and `ratings` calls)

> *Another season, another reason, to love Ruby :)*

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize this value before use, for example like this:

```
def do_foobar
  self.rating |= 1
  self.rating = (rating_score/rating)
end
```

Comment: That's not even what his question says.. his rating is over `ratings`, not `rating`.

Comment: There is a typo it is self.rating = (rating_score/ratings)

Comment: Yeah, my mistake, couldn't see this small difference.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
rating = rating_score/ratings if ratings != 0
```